# Unable to translate one custom post type slug in WPML

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

I have raised this issue on the WPML forums, but hoping someone here will be able to assist.

I am trying to translate the slug for a custom post type

The English URL is http://brigade-electronics.com/nl/products/backeye360/

The translated URL should be http://brigade-electronics.com/nl/producten/backeye360/

Instead I get a 404 error when navigating to the URL after enabling the translate slug option

Steps to duplicate the issue:

- Click On WPML -> Translation options
- Enable the Translate custom posts slugs (via WPML String Translation).
- Under the Custom posts settings (on the same page) Click the translate checkbox
- Added the translated slug for each language
- Hit save
- Navigate to the front end and see a 404 error on the products section only.

I have run all options in the troubleshooting page, to clear up the database.

This only seems to apply to certain pages within the product section. The weirdest part of this is the Canadian section of the site, as the term 'product' is in English therefore the URLs remain the same with or without the translated slugs in place, however, I still get the 404 error on these pages.

It is also worth noting that all other custom post types work without issue.

The custom post types have been registered in the standard way

```
function register_products_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => __( 'Products', '' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Product', '' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'label' => __( 'Products', '' ),
        'labels' => $labels,
        'description' => '',
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => false,
        'rest_base' => '',
        'has_archive' => false,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'map_meta_cap' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'products', 'with_front' => false ),
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_position' => 6,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-cart',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes' )
    );

    register_post_type( 'products', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'register_products_post_type' );
```

As per the below answer, the above code has been updated to

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type');
function create_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Products', 'general name of the post type' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Products', 'name for one object of this post type' ),

    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' =>  $labels, // An array that defines the different labels assigned to the custom post type
        'public' =>  true, // To show the custom post type on the WordPress dashboard
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes' ),
        'has_archive' =>  true, //Enables the custom post type archive at
        'hierarchical' =>  true, //Enables the custom post type to have a hierarchy
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' =>  _x('products', 'URL slug')),
    );
    register_post_type( 'products', $args );
    }
```

The new translation for the slug appears in the 'String Translation' section, when updating these strings, I get the same 404 error. If I leave these as English the products section works with no problem.

Thanks

Comment: where is the translation slug     $labels = array(
        'name' => __( 'Products', '' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Product', '' )
    ); - Text Domain is missing

Comment: This has not made a difference to all other custom post types, they are all set up the same, but will give it a try and let you know

Comment: Hi @MujeebuRahman adding a domain has not made a difference

Comment: Have u tried _e() ?

Comment: @MujeebuRahman __e() echos the string, which won't work in this instance

Comment: Have you tried disabling and re-enabling "Pretty Permalinks"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you flushed the rewrite rules?

Go to Settings > Permalinks and refresh.

> Note: If registering a post type inside of a plugin, call
>   flush_rewrite_rules() in your activation and deactivation hook (see
>   Flushing Rewrite on Activation below). If flush_rewrite_rules() is not
>   used, then you will have to manually go to Settings > Permalinks and
>   refresh your permalink structure before your custom post type will
>   show the correct structure.

source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type');
    function create_post_type() {
        $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Products', 'general name of the post type' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Products', 'name for one object of this post type' ),

       );
       $args = array(
         'labels' =>  $labels, // An array that defines the different labels assigned to the custom post type
         'public' =>  true, // To show the custom post type on the WordPress dashboard
         'supports' => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes' ),
         'has_archive' =>  true, //Enables the custom post type archive at 
         'hierarchical' =>  true, //Enables the custom post type to have a hierarchy
         'rewrite' => array( _x('slug' => 'products'), 'with_front' => false ),
    );
    register_post_type( 'products', $args );
    }
```

Comment: read this https://wpml.org/2016/08/how-to-create-and-translate-custom-post-types/

Comment: Afraid this doesn't make a difference, still getting a 404 error when switching to a translated slug.

Comment: Have you tried disabling and re-enabling "Pretty Permalinks"?

Comment: Yeah, no difference still.

Comment: @terrorfall Accept this answer so it can help other users who are having similar issue.

Comment: This answer doesn't solve the problem so it won't be any help to other users